# Using an initializer list of lambdas in a range-based loop

Tags: c++, c++11

With gcc 4.9 -std=c++14, I tried making a vector of lambdas:

```
vector<function<void ()>> v = {[]{cout << "foo";}, []{cout << "bar";}};
for (auto&& a: v) a();
```

And it worked pretty well. Then I tried passing the initializer list of lambdas to the range-based for directly:

```
for (auto&& a: {[]{cout << "foo";}, []{cout << "bar";}}) a();
```

And I got:

```
error: unable to deduce 'std::initializer_list<auto>&&' from '{<lambda closure object>main()::<lambda()>{}, <lambda closure object>main()::<lambda()>{}}'
```

Judging by the appearance of the error message, I made a wild guess that it is probably because "*lambda closure object*"s are built-in language terms, and not direct equivalents of std::function (so no real types).

What is the deeper cause of this? Also, could this be implementation-related, or is such behavior dictated by the specification?

Comment: [A braced initializer has no type](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU#t=1799). Which explains why you cant deduce it.

Comment: @Borgleader this is irrelevant here, *braced-init-list* in *range-based-for-loop* can be deduced as `initializer_list` of *something*

Comment: @Borgleader Yes that also crossed my mind. It seems though from the error message that the compiler tries to create a typed one. That makes me unsure whether it's a fault of the initializer list not having a type or of the lambda closure not working well with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each lambda has its own unique type. So you may not build std::initializer_list from lambdas of different types.

According to the C++ Standard (5.1.2 Lambda expressions)

> 3 The type of the lambda-expression (which is also **the type of the
>   closure object) is a unique**, unnamed nonunion class type — called the
>   closure type — whose properties are described below.

Also

> 6 The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression with no
>   lambda-capture has a public non-virtual nonexplicit const conversion
>   function to pointer to function with C++ language linkage (7.5) having
>   the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function
>   call operator.

Comment: So practically, a lambda closure that can be assigned to a variable of type `std::function<void ()>` has a different type of another closure that can be assigned to the same variable?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin There is no implicit conversion function from one lambda to another lambda.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin  Your point is wrong necause if you will write for ( int x : { 1, 'a' } ) the code will not be compiled.

Comment: @JerryCoffin But, maybe in that case the compiler infers the type of the initializer list from vector's initializer-list constructor, instead of the list's contents? (vector<T>(initializer_list<T>) )

Comment: @Jerry Coffin There is a difference between the range based for statement and your example.

Comment: @ThanasisPapoutsidakis: you're at least getting closer. Unfortunately, Vlad's made it obvious that he's going to try to make excuses for his answer instead of fixing it, so I'm not going to keep beating my head against the wall trying to get him act reasonably.

Answer (score 6):

Each lamdba has its own type, so compiler cannot deduced the type of the `initializer_list`.

You have to tell which type you want:

- For each lambda:

  - As your lambda doesn't capture variables, you may decay them to pointer to function with `+` as follow:

    ```
    for (auto&& a: {+[]{std::cout << "foo";}, +[]{std::cout << "bar";}}) a();
    ```
  - using `function<void()>`:

    ```
    for (auto&& a: {std::function<void()>([]{std::cout << "foo";}),
                    std::function<void()>([]{std::cout << "bar";})}) a();
    ```
- For the initializer_list:

  ```
  for (auto&& a: std::initializer_list<std::function<void()>>{
                     []{std::cout << "foo";}, 
                     []{std::cout << "bar";}}) a();
  ```

Answer (score 1):

One trick I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23597817/4224575) is to use a retrospective cast. So with such a tool at hand :

```
template<typename T>
struct memfun_type 
{
    using type = void;
};

template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename... Args>
struct memfun_type<Ret(Class::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using type = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;
};

template<typename F>
typename memfun_type<decltype(&F::operator())>::type
FFL(F const &func) 
{ // Function from lambda !
    return func;
}
```

you [**could write**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f832f8db1fee540) something like this

```
vector<function<void()>> v = { FFL([]{cout << "foo"; }), FFL([]{cout << "bar"; }) };

for (auto&& a : v) a();
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this approach fails with the use of C++14 generic lambdas.

Comment: @ildjarn Why is that ? ( I mean apart from the comment in the provided link? )

Comment: I hadn't seen it until just now, but yes, I'm referring to the same thing as R. Martinho Fernandes - it's not possible to take the address of a function template.

Comment: @ildjarn Thnx for the clarification! This means it would still work for plain old lambdas right?

Comment: For C++11 lambdas, yes, but once C++14 support is widespread, I think generic lambdas will themselves be considered plain old lambdas. ;-]

Answer (score 0):

Each lambda is an unrelated type.  As it happens, they can all be converted to `std::function<void()>`, but that is because `std::function` will claim to convert anything, and it will work when they are invokable with `void()` signature and copyable and destructible.

In the `vector` case, there is an `std::initializer_list<std::function<void()>>` constructor that is considered from its list of constructors.  This matches, is attempted, and compiles.

Without that argument (the list argument to the vector ctor) to match, the `{}` syntax instead looks inside at its contents for a common type.  There is no common type, so it fails.

The language does not search every type and template to find a possible common type between the two (unrelated) lambdas.  It will not read your mind.

You can do:

```
 using nullary = std::function<void()>;
 template<class T>
 using il=std::initializer_list<T>;
 for(auto f:il<nullary>{[]{ std::cout<<"hello";},[]{std::cout<<" world\n";}}){
   f();
 }
```