# C++11 Change `auto` Lambda to a different Lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, auto

Say I have the following variable containing a lambda:

```
auto a = [] { return true; };
```

And I want `a` to return `false` later on. Could I do something along the lines of this?

```
a = [] { return false; };
```

This syntax gives me the following errors:

```
binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 
'main::<lambda_a7185966f92d197a64e4878ceff8af4a>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands
        operand types are: lambda []bool ()->bool = lambda []bool ()->bool
```

Is there any way to achieve something like this? I would like to change the `auto` variable to a different lambda. I'm relitively a beginner so I may be missing some knowledge about `auto` or lambdas. Thanks.

Comment: There's the `bool b = true; auto a = [&b] { return b; }; b = false;` solution but this of course doesn't generalize to all situations.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Every lambda expression creates a new unique type, so the type of your first lambda is different from the type of your second ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82e1f1bfbaf084a3)). Additionally the copy-assignment operator of a lambda is defined as deleted ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fdea6ca65233aee)) so you're doubly-unable to do this. For a similar effect, you can have `a` be a `std::function` object though it'll cost you some performance

```
std::function<bool()> a = [] { return true; };
a = [] { return false; };
```

Answer (score 38):

A Lambda may be converted to a function pointer using the unary `+` operator like so:

```
+[]{return true;}
```

so long as the capture group is empty and it doesn't have `auto` arguments.<sup>1</sup>

If you do this, you may assign different lambdas to the same variable as long as the lambdas all have the same signature.

In your case,

```
auto a = +[]{return true;};
a = +[]{return false;};
```

<sup>[*Live example on Coliru*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/294e84c9e1c2cc69)</sup>

would both compile and act as you expect.<sup>2</sup> You may use the function pointers in the same way you would expect to use a lambda, since both will act as [*functors*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/356950/4892076).

---

<sup>1. In C++14, you can declare lambdas with `auto` as the argument type, like `[](auto t){}`. These are [*generic lambdas*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17233547/4892076), and have a templated `operator()`. Since a function pointer can't represent a templated function, the `+` trick won't work with generic lambdas.</sup>

<sup>2. Technically, you don't need the second `+` operator on the assignment. The lambda would convert to the function pointer type on assignment. I like the consistency, though.</sup>

Comment: The moment when C++ has officially entered the Perl realm!

Comment: @jaggedSpire I have needed this so bad so many times, and I thought the only solution was the other `function` answers to this question. How did you find out about this? I've never seen it before.

Comment: @JonathanMee I actually found it from following a related link in the sidebar, once upon a time: [A positive lambda: `+[]{}` - What sorcery is this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889028)

Answer (score 4):

Each lambda has a different type so you cannot change it. You could use a [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) to hold an arbitrary callable object, that can be changed at will.

```
std::function <bool ()> a = [] { return true; };
a = [] { return false; };
```

Comment: I guess Ryan beat you to it in posting the same thing.  But you’re missing a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Since `C++17` you can have the `std::function` template parameter deduced thanks to [Class template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). It even works with capturing lambdas:

```
int a = 24;

std::function f = [&a] (int p) { return p + a; };
f               = [&a] (int p) { return p - a; };
f               = []   (int p) { return p; };
```

This comes in handy with more complex signatures and even more with deduced return types.

Answer (score 1):

We may use [retrospective call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23597817/4224575) to convert lambda to std::function:

```
template<typename T>
struct memfun_type
{
  using type = void;
};

template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename... Args>
struct memfun_type<Ret(Class::*)(Args...) const>
{
  using type = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;
};

template<typename F>
typename memfun_type<decltype(&F::operator())>::type
FFL(F const &func)
{ // Function from lambda !
  return func;
}
```

After that we will be able to do (since 'a' is std::function type now ):

```
auto a = FFL([] { return false; });
a = FFL([] { return true; });
```

Comment: A bit more explanation would've been nice.